# Crawler for indexed_search ends with error page

Tags: error-handling, typo3-8.x

I use TYPO3 8.7.16 and the newest versions of indexed_search and crawler from repository. I followed this [manual](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/tutoriels/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html)

In my root template I added:

```
 config {
   absRefPrefix = /
   index_enable = 1
   index_externals = 1
}
```

In my crawler configuration I choose

(Protocol for crawling) keep page configured protocol

(Processing instruction filter) Re-indexing [tx_indexedsearch_reindex]

(Page Id of TypoScript root template) The folder with the root template

(Append cHash) chosen

1. I go to Web > Info
2. I switch to “Site Crawler” in the top dropdown menu
3. choose action “Site Crawling”
4. select my crawler configuration, update and crawl the sole URL that has been found
5. switch to the crawler log to show the pending queue; the URL of the page looks fine (   https://example.org/index.php?id=25&cHash= )
6. then I process manually the arrows before the date and get the following error message:

   Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1509296606 Failed to fetch error page "https://example.org/typo3/404.html",    reason: Client error: `GET https://example.org/typo3/404.html` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:     https://www.example.org/typo3/index.php?M=web_info&moduleToken=--AnonymizedToken--&qid_read=335&setID=0&id=25

What do I miss?

BTW my error page is https://example.org/404.html and works fine.

Comment: The error message is known: Bug #84098. 403 forbidden error on trying to access 404 page. https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84098